# How can I implements ProgressBar class?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, extends, implements

I want to edit `onDraw` method for my progressbar. But in my class I use `extends` to `Activity` class. When I search on the internet  I see  , I should extend to `ProgressBar` class. But I etends activity so How can I implements ProgressBar class?
my reason: I want to use progress bar which is filling right to left.

my code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)  {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(180,MainActivity.phone_width/2,MainActivity.phone_height/2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: good read! http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) is a child of [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).  [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is not, but it can contain one or more ViewGroups made up of one or more Views.

Create a subclass of `ProgressBar` and then include it in the View that is rendered by the `Activity`.